# How to match a geometric template of 2D boxes to fit another set of 2D boxes

Tags: geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I'm trying to find a match between a set of 2D boxes with coordinates (A) (from a template with known sizes and distances between boxes) to another set of 2D boxes with coordinates (B) (which may contain more boxes than A). They should match in terms of each box from A corresponds to a single Box in B. The boxes in A together form a "stamp" which is assymmetrical in atleast one dimension.

[Illustration of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBtbk.png)

*explanation: "Stanz" in the illustration is a box from set A.*

One might even think of the Set A as only 2D points (the centerpoint of the box) to make it simpler.

The end result will be to know which A box corresponds to which B box.

I can only think of very specific ways of doing this, tailored to a specific layout of boxes, is there any known generic ways of dealing with this forms of matching/search problems and what are they called?

Edit: Possible solution

I have come up with one possible solution, looking for all the possible rotations at each possible B center position for a single box from set A. Here all of the points in A would be rotated and compared against the distance to B centers. Not sure if this is a good way.

[Looking for the possible rotations at each B centerpoint- solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYYqa.png)

Comment: Are there any other constraints on the problem, such as maximum number of points/boxes, only 90-degree rotations allowed, or anything like that? [Edit: Also, are the coordinates integers, or real numbers?]

Comment: There will be a low number of boxes in set A and B (less than 20 in each). rotation can be any degree. Coordinates are integers. Since the box size of each A and B are known, the ratio is known (we get the scaling for free)

Comment: Couple more questions. You say the rotations can be arbitrary and the coordinates are integers, but it seems that would mean that a rotated configuration might only be an approximation of the original configuration. Is that correct? (Of course that's the case with floating-point values as well, but the effect may be more pronounced with integers.) Also, do the box sizes matter at all, or is it the case that they have no bearing and can be ignored? (Apologies if you've already made that clear and I'm just not understanding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the transformation between the template and its presence in B can be entirely defined (actually, over-defined) by two matching points.

So here's a simple approach which is *kind of* performant. First, put all the points in B into a kD-tree. Now, pick a canonical "first" point in A, and hypothesize matching it to each of the points in B. To check whether it matches a particular point in B, pick a canonical "second" point in A and measure its distance to the "first" point. Then, use a standard kD proximity-bounding query to find all the points in B which are roughly that distance from your hypothesized matched "first" point in B. For each of those, determine the transformation between A and B, and for each of the other points in A, determine whether there's a point in A at roughly the right place (again, using the kD-tree), early-outing with the first unmatched point.

The worst-case performance there can get quite bad with pathological cases (`O(n^3 log n)`, I think) but in general I would expect roughly `O(n log n)` for well-behaved data with a low threshold. Note that the thresholding is a bit rough-and-ready, and the results can depend on your choice of "first" and "second" points.

Comment: If there are no missing points in the set B, it is advisable to take the canonical points in A as far apart as possible. This should will minimize the number of possible candidate pairs in B.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It depends on the relative size of the clouds. I think the main advantage of picking points far apart is that the reconstructed transformation is more robust. But it makes it slower to find the second point in the kD-tree.

Comment: No, it does not make it slower, on the opposite. Because there are less pairs that can fit in the set B.

Comment: I don't see how that follows.... the area of a ring around a vertex with a particular radius and thickness (the region around the first point within which one can look for the second point) will be proportional to the ring's radius, so there'll be more points to find for any first point. Unless you're thinking that the two clouds will have roughly equal relative size, rather than B being significantly bigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an idea than an answer, but it's too long for a comment. I asked some additional questions in a comment above, but the answers may not be particular relevant, so I'll go ahead and offer some thoughts in the meantime.

As you may know, point matching is its own problem domain, and if you search for 'point matching algorithm', you'll find various articles, papers, and other resources. It seems though that an ad hoc solution might be appropriate here (one that's simpler than more generic algorithms that are available).

I'll assume that the input point set can only be rotated, and not also flipped. If this idea were to work though, it should also work with flipping - you'd just have to run the algorithm separately for each flipped configuration.

In your example image, you've matched a point from set A with a point from set B so that they're coincident. Call this shared point the 'anchor' point. You'd need to do this for every combination of a point from set A and a point from set B until you found a match or exhausted the possibilities. The problem then is to determine if a match can be made given one of these matched point pairs.

It seems that for a given anchor point, a necessary but not sufficient condition for a match is that a point from set A and a point from set B can be found that are approximately the same distance from the anchor point. (What 'approximately' means would depend on the input, and would need to be tuned appropriately given that you're using integers.) This condition is met in your example image in that the center point of each point set is (approximately) the same distance from the anchor point. (Note that there could be multiple pairs of points that meet this condition, in which case you'd have to examine each such pair in turn.)

Once you have such a pair - the center points in your example - you can use some simple trigonometry and linear algebra to rotate set A so that the points in the pair coincide, after which the two point sets are locked together at two points and not just one. In your image that would involve rotating set A about 135 degrees clockwise. Then you check to see if every point in set B has a point in set A with which it's coincident, to within some threshold. If so, you have a match.

In your example, this fails of course, because the rotation is not actually a match. Eventually though, if there's a match, you'll find the anchor point pair for which the test succeeds.

I realize this would be easier to explain with some diagrams, but I'm afraid this written explanation will have to suffice for the moment. I'm not positive this would work - it's just an idea. And maybe a more generic algorithm would be preferable. But, if this did work, it might have the advantage of being fairly straightforward to implement.

[Edit: Perhaps I should add that this is similar to your solution, except for the additional step to allow for only testing a subset of the possible rotations.]

[Edit: I think a further refinement may be possible here. If, after choosing an anchor point, matching is possible via rotation, it should be the case that for every point *p* in B there's a point in A that's (approximately) the same distance from the anchor point as *p* is. Again, it's a necessary but not sufficient condition, but it allows you to quickly eliminate cases where a match isn't possible via rotation.]

Answer (score 0):

Below follows a finished solution in python without kD-tree and without early outing candidates. A better way is to do the implementation yourself according to Sneftel but if you need anything quick and with a plot this might be useful.

[image: Plot of fit by algorithm below]

Plot shows the different steps, starts off with just the template as a collection of connected lines. Then it is translated to a point in B where the distances between A and B points fits the best. Finally it is rotated.

[image]

In this example it was important to also match up which of the template positions was matched to which boundingbox position, so its an extra step in the end. There might be some deviations in the code compared to the outline above.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def to_polar(pos_array):
    x = pos_array[:, 0]
    y = pos_array[:, 1]

    length = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    t = np.arctan2(y, x)
    zip_list = list(zip(length, t))
    array_polar = np.array(zip_list)
    return array_polar

def to_cartesian(pos):
    # first element radius
    # second is angle(theta)
    # Converting polar to cartesian coordinates
    radius = pos[0]
    theta = pos[1]

    x = radius * math.cos(theta)
    y = radius * math.sin(theta)
    return x,y

def calculate_distance_points(p1,p2):
    return np.sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2+(p1[1]-p2[1])**2)

def find_closest_point_inx(point, neighbour_set):
    shortest_dist = None
    closest_index = -1
    # Find the point in the secondary array that is the closest
    for index,curr_neighbour in enumerate(neighbour_set):
        distance = calculate_distance_points(point, curr_neighbour)
        if shortest_dist is None or distance < shortest_dist:
            shortest_dist = distance
            closest_index = index
    return closest_index

# Find the sum of distances between each point in primary to the closest one in secondary
def calculate_agg_distance_arrs(primary,secondary):
    total_distance = 0
    for point in primary:
        closest_inx = find_closest_point_inx(point, secondary)
        dist = calculate_distance_points(point, secondary[closest_inx])
        total_distance += dist
    return total_distance

# returns a set of <primary_index,neighbour_index>
def pair_neighbours_by_distance(primary_set, neighbour_set, distance_limit):
    pairs = {}
    for num, point in enumerate(primary_set):
        closest_inx = find_closest_point_inx(point, neighbour_set)
        if calculate_distance_points(neighbour_set[closest_inx], point) > distance_limit:
            closest_inx = None
        pairs[num]=closest_inx
    return pairs

def rotate_array(array, angle,rot_origin=None):
    if rot_origin is not None:
        array = np.subtract(array,rot_origin)
    # clockwise rotation
    theta = np.radians(angle)
    c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
    R = np.array(((c, -s), (s, c)))
    rotated = np.matmul(array, R)
    if rot_origin is not None:
        rotated = np.add(rotated,rot_origin)
    return rotated



# Finds out a point in B_set and a rotation where the points in SetA have the best alignment towards SetB.
def find_stamp_rotation(A_set, B_set):
    # Step 1
    anchor_point_A = A_set[0]
    # Step 2. Convert all points to polar coordinates with anchor as origin
    A_anchor_origin = A_set - anchor_point_A
    anchor_A_polar = to_polar(A_anchor_origin)

    print(anchor_A_polar)
    # Step 3 for each point in B
    score_tuples = []
    for num_anchor, B_anchor_point_try in enumerate(B_set):
        # Step 3.1
        B_origin_rel_point = B_set-B_anchor_point_try
        B_polar_rp_origin = to_polar(B_origin_rel_point)
        # Step 3.3 select arbitrary point q from Ap
        point_Aq = anchor_A_polar[1]
        # Step 3.4 test each rotation, where pointAq is rotated to each B-point (except the B anchor point)
        for try_rot_point_B in [B_rot_point for num_rot, B_rot_point in enumerate(B_polar_rp_origin) if num_rot != num_anchor]:
            # positive rotation is clockwise
            # Step 4.1 Rotate Ap by the angle between q and n
            angle_to_try = try_rot_point_B[1]-point_Aq[1]
            rot_try_arr = np.copy(anchor_A_polar)
            rot_try_arr[:,1]+=angle_to_try
            cart_rot_try_arr = [to_cartesian(e) for e in rot_try_arr]
            cart_B_rp_origin = [to_cartesian(e) for e in B_polar_rp_origin]

            distance_score = calculate_agg_distance_arrs(cart_rot_try_arr, cart_B_rp_origin)

            score_tuples.append((B_anchor_point_try,angle_to_try,distance_score))
            # Step 4.3


    lowest=None
    for b_point,angle,distance in score_tuples:
        print("point:{} angle(rad):{} distance(sum):{}".format(b_point,360*(angle/(2*math.pi)),distance))
        if lowest is None or distance < lowest[2]:
            lowest = b_point, 360*angle/(2*math.pi), distance

    return lowest


def test_example():
    ax = plt.subplot()
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.title('Fit Template to BBoxes by translation and rotation')
    plt.xlim(-20, 20)
    plt.ylim(-20, 20)
    ax.set_xticks(range(-20,20), minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(range(-20,20), minor=True)

    template = np.array([[-10,-10],[-10,10],[0,0],[10,-10],[10,10], [0,20]])
    # Test Bboxes are Rotated 40 degree, translated 2,2
    rotated = rotate_array(template,40)
    rotated = np.subtract(rotated,[2,2])


    # Adds some extra bounding boxes as noise
    for i in range(8):
        rotated = np.append(rotated,[[random.randrange(-20,20), random.randrange(-20,20)]],axis=0)

    # Scramble entries in array and return the position change.
    rnd_rotated = rotated.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(rnd_rotated)
    element_positions = []

    # After shuffling, looks at which index the "A"-marks has ended up at. For later comparison to see that the algo found the correct answer.
    # This is to represent the actual case, where I will get a bunch of unordered bboxes.
    rnd_map = {}
    indexes_translation = [num2 for num,point in enumerate(rnd_rotated) for num2,point2 in enumerate(rotated) if point[0]==point2[0] and point[1]==point2[1]]
    for num,inx in enumerate(indexes_translation):
        rnd_map[num]=inx

    # algo part 1/3
    b_point,angle,_ = find_stamp_rotation(template,rnd_rotated)

    # Plot for visualization
    legend_list = np.empty((0,2))
    leg_template = plt.plot(template[:,0],template[:,1],c='r')
    legend_list = np.append(legend_list,[[leg_template[0],'1. template-pattern']],axis=0)
    leg_bboxes = plt.scatter(rnd_rotated[:,0],rnd_rotated[:,1],c='b',label="scatter")
    legend_list = np.append(legend_list,[[leg_bboxes,'2. bounding boxes']],axis=0)
    leg_anchor = plt.scatter(b_point[0],b_point[1],c='y')
    legend_list = np.append(legend_list,[[leg_anchor,'3. Discovered bbox anchor point']],axis=0)

    # algo part 2/3
    # Superimpose A onto B by A[0] to b_point
    offset = b_point - template[0]
    super_imposed_A = template + offset

    # Plot superimposed, but not yet rotated
    leg_s_imposed = plt.plot(super_imposed_A[:,0],super_imposed_A[:,1],c='k')
    #plt.legend(rubberduckz, "superimposed template on anchor")
    legend_list = np.append(legend_list,[[leg_s_imposed[0],'4. Templ superimposed on Bbox']],axis=0)
    print("Superimposed A on B by A[0] to {}".format(b_point))
    print(super_imposed_A)

    # Rotate, now the template should match pattern of bboxes
    # algo part 3/4
    super_imposed_rotated_A = rotate_array(super_imposed_A,-angle,rot_origin=super_imposed_A[0])

    # Show the beautiful match in a last plot
    leg_s_imp_rot = plt.plot(super_imposed_rotated_A[:,0],super_imposed_rotated_A[:,1],c='g')
    legend_list = np.append(legend_list,[[leg_s_imp_rot[0],'5. final fit']],axis=0)
    plt.legend(legend_list[:,0], legend_list[:,1],loc="upper left")
    plt.show()

    # algo part 4/4
    pairs = pair_neighbours_by_distance(super_imposed_rotated_A, rnd_rotated, 10)
    print(pairs)
    for inx in range(len(pairs)):
        bbox_num = pairs[inx]
        print("template id:{}".format(inx))
        print("bbox#id:{}".format(bbox_num))
        #print("original_bbox:{}".format(rnd_map[bbox_num]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_example()
```

[image: Result on actual image with bounding boxes]
Result on actual image with bounding boxes. Here it can be seen that the scaling is incorrect which makes the template a bit off but it will still be able to pair up and thats the desired end-result in my case.